# COUNTIFS with OR but no SUM

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to count the number of items that fit at least one criteria. But my actual formula count 2 instead of 1 when an item fits 2 criteria at the same time.

Considering the following example :

```
Article  |  Rate 1  |  Rate 2  |  Rate 3  | Language

   1     |    12%   |    54%   |    6%    | English

   2     |    65%   |    55%   |    34%   | English

   3     |    59%   |    12%   |    78%   | French

   4     |    78%   |    8%    |    47%   | English

   5     |    12%   |    11%   |    35%   | English
```

How do you count the number of article in English with at least one success rate over 50%.

Right now my formula counts 4 instead of 3, because the article 2 counts for 2. (I'm on google sheets)

Thank you for your help.

Best,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that data is in columns A:E, you could use:

```
=COUNT(filter(A2:A6,E2:E6="English",(D2:D6>=50%)+(C2:C6>=0.5)+(B2:B6>=0.5)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(E2:E6="english"), SIGN((B2:B6>0.5)+(C2:C6>0.5)+(D2:D6>0.5)))
```

[image]